# can anybody help me regards this error m doing work on magento 2 after installing sample data i got this?

Tags: magento2

[image]

i found this issue anybody can resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Please check your di.xml file in `app/etc` folder,

or replace that file with a new magento file.

Run below mentioned commands:

```
php bin/magento c:f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated app/etc
```

Hope it work for you,